# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath' Error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

while captcha:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/button'
    ).click()
except (
    common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException,
    common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException
):
    continue
driver.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
print('[!] Running...')
captcha = False
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUKUt.png)

This is my code, I've been trying to resolve the error for hours and everything I've done still causes the error, can anyone help me?

I tried changing the prefix and nothing

Answer (score 0):

Please check your selenium version, That's not the right expression in selenium4.1......

In selenium version 4.... right way is:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/button').click()
```

In version 3.... can user `driver.find_element_by_xpath` but version 4.... not

Plus, watch out iframe.